# Android camera-2 API Recording Preview was squished in Portrait Recording in Samsung Galaxy S8

Tags: android, android-camera2, samsung-s8

I am facing the **squished preview** in Samsung S8, I'm using camera-2 API for recording in my project with the support for only **1920x1080** resolution. Quality of recording is good, but the preview is not proper in S8. I tried this solution [Samsung Galaxy S8 full screen mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694526/samsung-galaxy-s8-full-screen-mode), but it doesn't help in my issue.

Please help and thanks in advance.

***Here is my code which implemented for camera:***

```
    /*To maintain the aspect ratio 16:9 for record video*/
      private  Size chooseVideoSize(Size[] choices) {
        for (Size size : choices) {
            int orientation = getActivityContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                if((size.getWidth()/16) == (size.getHeight()/9) && size.getWidth() <=3840 ) {
                    return size;
                }
            } else {
                if((size.getWidth()/16) == (size.getHeight()/9) && (size.getWidth() <=1280 ) ) {
                    return size;
                }
            }
        }
        return choices[choices.length - 1];
    }
    /*
     * Given {@code choices} of {@code Size}s supported by a camera, chooses the smallest one whose
     * width and height are at least as large as the respective requested values, and whose aspect
     * ratio matches with the specified value.
     */
    private  Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height, Size aspectRatio) {
        List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
        int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
        int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
        double ratio = (double) h / w;
        for (Size size : choices) {
            int orientation = getActivityContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                if((size.getWidth()/16) == (size.getHeight()/9) && size.getWidth() <=3840 ) {
                    return size;
                }
            } else {
                if((size.getWidth()/16) == (size.getHeight()/9) && (size.getWidth() <=1280 ) ) {
                    return size;
                }
            }
        }
        // Pick the smallest of those, assuming we found any
        if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
        } else {
            return choices[0];
        }
    }
    /*
     * Compares two {@code Size}s based on their areas.
     */
    static class CompareSizesByArea implements Comparator<Size> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
            // We cast here to ensure the multiplications won't overflow
            return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
                    (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
        }
    }
    /*
     * Starts a background thread and its {@link Handler}.
     */
    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        try {
            mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
            mBackgroundThread.start();
            mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
        }catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
    /*
     * Stops the background thread and its {@link Handler}.
     */
    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        if(mBackgroundThread!=null){
            mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
            try {
                mBackgroundThread.join();
                mBackgroundThread = null;
                mBackgroundHandler = null;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
            }
            String mCameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[cameraId];
            // Choose the sizes for camera preview and video recording
            characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            try {
                mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
                maximumZoomLevel = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM);
                if (map == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot get available preview/video sizes");
                }
                mVideoSize = chooseVideoSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class));
                mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), width, height, mVideoSize);
                int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
                if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
                } else {
                    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
                }
                if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    configureTransform(width, height);
                }
                boolean result = checkAccessCameraPermission();
                if (result) {
                    manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, null);
                }

            }catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}finally {
                map=null;
                Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivityContext, "Cannot access the camera.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.");
        }
    }
    /*
     * Start the camera preview.
     */
    private void startPreview() {
        if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            closePreviewSession();
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
            mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Collections.singletonList(previewSurface),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            mPreviewSession = session;
                            updatePreview();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivityContext, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Update the camera preview. {@link #startPreview()} needs to be called in advance.
     */
    private void updatePreview() {
        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(mPreviewBuilder);
            HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
            try {
                thread.start();
                if(zoom!=null){
                    try{
                        mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, zoom);
                        mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), mPreviewSessionCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                    }catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
                }else{
                    mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
                }
            }catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}finally {
                thread=null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(CaptureRequest.Builder builder) {
        builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    }

    /*
     * Configures the necessary {@link android.graphics.Matrix} transformation to `mTextureView`.
     * This method should not to be called until the camera preview size is determined in
     * openCamera, or until the size of `mTextureView` is fixed.
     */
    private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {
        if (null == mTextureView || null == mPreviewSize) {
            return;
        }
        int rotation = getActivityContext.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
        RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
        float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
        if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
            bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
            matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            float scale = Math.max((float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),(float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
            matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
        }else if (Surface.ROTATION_0 == rotation) {
            bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
            matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            float scale=Math.max((float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth(), (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
            matrix.postRotate(0, centerX, centerY);
        }else if(Surface.ROTATION_180== rotation){
            bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
            matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            float scale=Math.max((float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth(), (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
            matrix.postRotate(0, centerX, centerY);
        }
        try {
            mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
        }catch (Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}finally {
            bufferRect=null;
            viewRect=null;
            matrix=null;
        }
    }
```

[image: Create Screen(Before Recording Strecthing Preview in S8)]
[image: After Recording Recorded video is good]

Comment: This link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43694526/samsung-galaxy-s8-full-screen-mode?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @gokul I tried that link, and this added in my question

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, it is a late reply, but it helps. In Android, CameraX is helping to avoid the squeeze the screen by using the default method aspectRatio().

**Here is my code,**

```
/**
     *  Detecting the most suitable aspect ratio for current dimensions
     *
     *  @param width - preview width
     *  @param height - preview height
     *  @return suitable aspect ratio
     */
    private fun aspectRatio(width: Int, height: Int): Int {
        val previewRatio = max(width, height).toDouble() / min(width, height)
        if (abs(previewRatio - RATIO_4_3_VALUE) <= abs(previewRatio - RATIO_16_9_VALUE)) {
            return AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3
        }
        return AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9
    }
```

I recommend, migrate into CameraX is the best approach.
Credit goes to this repository author
[CameraX-Demo](https://github.com/robertlevonyan/camerax-demo)